# What's the difference between these two methods of creating an account via Parity?

Tags: parity, accounts

In Parity, as explained in [this tutorial for setting up a PoA](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Demo-PoA-tutorial), there are three methods for creating Ethereum accounts: Via RPC calls, via the UI, and via `parity account new`.

The UI obviously seems to wrapping the RPC calls, so we can discard the UI for the sake of this discussion. I've observed the following:

- The RPC calls will deterministically create an ICAP address. I'm specifically running `parity_newAccountFromPhrase` and I seed this with a random phrase from parity `parity_generateSecretPhrase`.
- The command line option `parity account new` does not seem to give me an ICAP address or the possibility of getting a recovery phrase.

So what's the rationale behind this? Is there a way for me to get a non-ICAP compatible address from the RPC calls? Is there a way for me to get a recovery phrase from the command line option?

I'm specifically asking with regard to private PoA chains.

EDIT: ICAP, not ICAN.

Comment: Why do you use Parity? A lot of people who were using it now lost all of their money.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only accounts generated from phrase result in an ICAP-compatible address, namely `parity_newAccountFromPhrase`.

> Is there a way for me to get a non-ICAP compatible address from the RPC calls?

All other methods (CLI, RPC) do not yield such addresses. For RPC that is:

- `personal_newAccount`
- `parity_newAccountFromSecret`
- `parity_newAccountFromWallet`

> Is there a way for me to get a recovery phrase from the command line option?

No, but there is a rust crate: https://github.com/paritytech/wordlist

Comment: Ok! So the CLI `parity account new` and the RPC  `parity_newAccount` are functionally equivalent?

Comment: `personal_newAccount`, but yes.