# Parity New Account: no seed?

Tags: parity, accounts

Using Parity 1.7.x, if you type "parity account new" you have to type in a password.  But there's no seed being generated.  Does that mean this wallet can't be restored without the original key?

Or is there a way to generate the seed (not from the UI)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly, the CLI generates just a random key.

See also this answer: [What's the difference between these two methods of creating an account via Parity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/30752/whats-the-difference-between-these-two-methods-of-creating-an-account-via-parit/31283#31283)

> Or is there a way to generate the seed (not from the UI)?

Yes, via RPC:

1. `parity_generateSecretPhrase`
2. `parity_newAccountFromPhrase`

Check the docs for usage examples:

- [parity](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-parity-module)
- [parity_accounts](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-parity_accounts-module)

Comment: parity_generateSecretPhrase does not appear anywhere on the page you linked to.

Comment: Sorry, one is in [parity](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-parity-module) and one is in [parity_accounts](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-parity_accounts-module) module.

Comment: I still don't see it.  There is "parity_newAccountFromSecret" but that is the opposite.  The question is how to generate the seed when you have a working key that you created on the Parity command line (which does not give you a seed).

Comment: Ah here it is: https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-parity-module#parity_generatesecretphrase